# How can I implement an animated intro screen as IFTTT's?

Tags: ios

I saw how awesome IFTTT's intro screen is and I also want to implement something that awesome in my app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently, I created a UIScrollView subclass called `DRDynamicSlideShow` to easily implement touch-interactive slide shows like IFTTT's. Check it out, it takes only 1 line of code per animation!

https://github.com/Dromaguirre/DRDynamicSlideShow

Comment: Its nice. But some thing i noticed that you cant add anything on page > 1 with animation "appear from left". You have to trick or a set of animation like keep alpha 0 if you are less than such page, to do so. The concept is easy. If you don't care about my concern.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, IFTTT has open sourced the framework they created for this. It's called JazzHands and it's [available on GitHub](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands):

> `Jazz Hands` is a simple, keyframe based animation framework for `UIKit`. Animations can be controlled via gestures, scroll views, kvo, or ReactiveCocoa.
>
> `Jazz Hands` is used extensively in IFTTT for iPhone, most famously in the app intro.

Comment: Its nice. But some thing i noticed that you cant add anything on page > 1 with animation "appear from left". You have to trick or a set of animation like keep alpha 0 if you are less than such page, to do so. The concept is easy. If you don't care about my concern.