# How to animate element from one view controller to other in an UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have seen in IFTTT app that they animate objects from one view controller to other. Can someone tell me how to do that?
A video is there in the link for the reference, please check that.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxdcR6CKy3QmZWd2TXpxeWFXb3M

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement an animated intro screen as IFTTT's?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328677/how-can-i-implement-an-animated-intro-screen-as-ifttts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incidentally, IFTTT open sourced [the framework](https://github.com/IFTTT/JazzHands) they used to make that exact intro.

Comment: Thanks Chris! But could you please explain what actually goes behind the curtain ?